# C Programming, confusion about pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code

```
char buffer[1024];  
void *temp= (void *)(buffer + 4);
int *size= (int *)temp;
```

I believe the third line can be simplified by changing `temp` to `buffer`.
I thought that one of the following would be correct, but both gave me an error (segmentation fault).

```
int *size = (int *)(buffer + 4)
```

or

```
int *size = (int *)*(buffer + 4)
```

What is the correct answer? Pointers are killing me.

Comment: `int *size = (int *)(buffer + 4)` This doesn't look like it would cause a segfault by itself. What are you trying to do with the pointer, and why aren't you telling us this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for the confusion; it was just an error, not segmentation fault. 

I was asking for help to solve 'complicated concept of pointers for beginner' problem. Following was the answer.

```
int *size = (int *)(&buffer[4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this code with no segfault. Comments and print out will give some representation.

```
int main (void)
{
 char buffer[11] = {'f', 'e', 'e', 'd', 't', 'h', 'e', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'e'} ;


 printf("Buffer's address in the memory:0x%x\n", buffer); //all three are the same
 printf("Buffer's address in the memory:0x%x\n", & buffer); //all three are the same
 printf("Buffer's address in the memory:0x%x\n", & buffer[0]); //all three are the same

 unsigned char a;
 for (a=0;a<11;a++)
  printf( "%c", buffer[a]);


 void *temp= (void *)(buffer + 4);
 int * size= (int *)temp;

 printf ("\ntemp:0x%x\n", temp);
 printf ("size:0x%x\n", size);
 printf ("size:%c\n", *size); 

 size    = (int *)(buffer + 4);




 printf ("\n(int *)*(buffer + 4): 0x%x\n",(int *)*(buffer + 4));
 size  = *(char *)(buffer + 4);
 printf("size:%c\n",size); // 't''s ASCII code
 printf("size:0x%x\n",size); // 't'
}
```